# mds_stores prevents me from ejecting Time Machine disk

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, spotlight

I know many people have complained about being unable to eject a Time Machine disk.  The usual response I have found online is to download and use "What's Keeping Me?" to find out what process is accessing the disk. Well, I have done that, and it turns out the culprit is mds_stores -- in other words, Spotlight.

Now Spotlight *shouldn't* be indexing my Time Machine volume -- I have it excluded in the Spotlight privacy pane.  Killing the mds_stores process allows me to safely eject the TM disk, so in a sense my problem is "solved".  But why is this happening?

Comment: Is it happening every time?

Comment: @IronCraftMan No, but often enough that it's getting really irritating.

Comment: have you tried restating your Mac in safe mode and seeing if it works?